# No collisions being detected in subclassed nodes

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I'm writing a game. It is not detecting any collisions, even though I can see the physics bodies as I have that view turned on.

To set-up the physics world in the game scene, I've coded the following above the class declaration:

```
struct PhysicsCategory {
    static let None: UInt32 = 0
    static let Chicken: UInt32 = 0b1
    static let Edge: UInt32 = 0b10
}
```

Then, within the actual class of the scene:

```
override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
    setupNodes()
    setupTrial()

    let playableRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size.width/2, height: size.height/2)
    self.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFrom: playableRect)
    self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self
    self.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Edge
    self.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Chicken

    // This is important for handling all the custom events
    enumerateChildNodes(withName: "//*", using: { node, _ in
        // we need to limit this to chickens only
        if let customNode = node as? CustomNodeEvents {
            customNode.didMoveToScene()
        }
    })
}
```

Here is the code to detect collisions:

```
func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
    print("something happened")
    let collision = contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask |    contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask

    if collision == PhysicsCategory.Chicken | PhysicsCategory.Edge {
        print("it works!")
    }
}
```

The nodes I'd like to animate are chickens. I want the game to detect when they collide with the edges of the world above.

My chicken subclass is this:

```
class TargetNode: SKSpriteNode, CustomNodeEvents, InteractiveNode {

func didMoveToScene() {
    isUserInteractionEnabled = true

    anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
    let playableRect = CGRect(x: self.anchorPoint.x, y: self.anchorPoint.y, width: self.size.width, height: self.size.height)

    physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFrom: playableRect)
    physicsBody!.isDynamic = true
    physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Chicken
    physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Edge | PhysicsCategory.Chicken
    physicsBody!.velocity = CGVector(dx: 100, dy: 0)
}
}
```

EDIT: The nodes are being added to the scene using this method in the game scene file.

```
func generateItems(targetNumber: Int, target: Bool) {
    let movingItems = true
    for _ in 0...(targetNumber - 1) {
        if (target) {
            let name = createTarget()
            let targetNode = TargetNode(imageNamed: name)
            targetNode.name = name
            fgNode.addChild(targetNode)
            targetNode.position = generateRandomLocation()
            //if movingItems { animateTargets(targetNode) }
       }
}
```

Comment: Where are you adding the nodes to the scene?

Comment: I'm generating a bunch of nodes using the function added in my edit above.

Comment: It looks as thought both the edge and the chicks have physicsBodies constructed from edgeLoops. I don't think these can collide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

setting your chicken to a `SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFrom :_)` is a bad idea. instead try `SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf :_)` to draw a rectangle shape around your chicken, the type of shape you want to draw can vary, check the docs for more information.

Moreover to check weather the chickens have made contact with the `playableRect`

remove  `self.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Chicken` because we don't want to check if the rect has made contact with the chicken we want to know if the chicken has made contact with the playable Rect. So keep `contactTestBitMask` on the chicken.

remove : `| PhysicsCategory.Chicken` from your chicken subclass, unless you want to check weather the chickens collide with each other as well.

lastly: check for collisions, if the chicken makes contact with the playableRect

```
  func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {

    if contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCategory.Chicken && contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCategory.Edge {
       print("Chickens have collided with edge")
    }

    }
```

Comment: Thanks. Just out of curiousity, why would changing the SKPhysicsBody shape change anything?

Comment: Thats because Edge Based Physics bodies cannot interact with other edge based bodies. can i get a thumbs up? :)